# weird behaviour when removing and adding rows to a form

Tags: angular

Basically I have a template driven form with a couple of existing rows. There is an Add button to add a row and a remove button per row to remove the row.

```
<form>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let model of models; index as i;">
        <input type="text" id="name-{{i}}" name="name-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="model.name"/>
        <input type="text" id="value-{{i}}" name="value-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="model.value"/>
        <button type="button" (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
        <br/>
    </ng-container>
</form>
<button type="button" (click)="add()">Add</button>
```

And here is the component:

```
export class AppComponent  {

    models = [{
        name: "name 1",
        value: "value 1"
    },{
        name: "name 2",
        value: "value 2"
    },{
        name: "name 3",
        value: "value 3"
    }];

    add() {
        this.models.push({
            name: "new",
            value: "new"
        });
    }

    remove(index: number) {
        this.models.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Replication Steps:

1. Remove the 2nd row.
2. Add a new row

Now you can see the 2nd row and the 3rd row are both "new". Anyone has any ideas?
You can copy & paste this code into stackblitz and it will just work, or break really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell angular to track your items with [`trackBy`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy). Currently when you are removing the second item, your form value looks like:

```ts
"name-0": "name 1",
"value-0": "value 1",
"name-2": "name 3",
"value-2": "value 3"
```

The index is not updated, so when you push a new item, it takes the `name-2` and `value-2` place and therefore updates "both" the second and third value. If you use `trackBy`, angular will track the unique index. So add:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let model of models; index as i; trackBy:trackbyFn">
```

and the function:

```ts
trackbyFn(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bujnts?file=src/app/app.component.ts;)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `ids` in your code for your `name`.

If you work with UNIQUE object:

```
models = [{
    name: "name 1",
    value: "value 1",
    id:Math.random()
},{
    name: "name 2",
    value: "value 2",
    id:Math.random()
},{
    name: "name 3",
    value: "value 3",
    id:Math.random()
}];

add() {
    this.models.push({
        name: "new",
        value: "new",
        id:Math.random()
    });
}
```

and

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let model of models; index as i;">
        <input type="text" id="name-{{model.id}}" name="name-{{model.id}}" [(ngModel)]="model.name"/>
    <input type="text" id="value-{{model.id}}" name="value-{{model.id}}" [(ngModel)]="model.value"/>
    <button type="button" (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
</ng-container>
```

then it will work